# extract (string) file contents from memory stream

Tags: c#, api, http, asp.net-core, stream

I've got a file that lives on Azure Data Lake Store, and I'm writing an api endpoint to retrieve the contents of that file as a string. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting an empty string when I try and read the stream. Here's what i'm working with:

```
[HttpGet("api/rundata/solutions/{solutionId}/dates/{dateId}/files/{fileId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string solutionId, string dateId, string fileId, string account, string key, string mode="data")
{
    var dataLakeFileSystemClient = _dataLakeTools.GetDataLakeFileSystemClient(account, key, "rundata");
    var downloadResponse = await _dataLakeTools.DownloadFileAsync(dataLakeFileSystemClient, $"{solutionId}/{dateId}", fileId);

    //returns the file itself
    if (mode.Equals("file"))
    { 
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            downloadResponse.Value.Content.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream");
        }
    } 

    //returns the contents of the file as a string
    else if (mode.Equals("data"))
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            downloadResponse.Value.Content.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                string contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return Ok(contents);
            }
        }
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Currently, the response that returns the file is working fine and I can open up the file on my PC and read it's contents. the response that uses a StreamReader to return the contents of the file is returning an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is the `memoryStream` position is set to the end of the stream after `CopyTo`. You can either reset the `MemoryStream` with [`Seek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.seek?view=netcore-3.1):

> Sets the position within the current stream to the specified value.

```
downloadResponse.Value.Content.CopyTo(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

or pass the `downloadResponse.Value.Content` into the `StreamReader` constructor, which I'd assume is just a `NetworkStream`.

```
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(downloadResponse.Value.Content))
```

Comment: Just a follow-up question, why does this work? Where does metadata get stored (if it's not part of the stream), like the filename?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips This is potentially another question, i am not really familiar with these types of things